# Is there a smooth function to approximate maximum function of a vector?

Tags: functional-analysis, vectors

I want to find functions to approximate maximum function of a vector. Is there a smooth function to approximate infinity norm of a vector?

Comment: You could take $\|\cdot\|_p$ where $p$ is large.

Comment: Since $\|x\|_p \to \|x\|_\infty$, you could approximate $\sqrt[p]{\cdot}$ in some smooth way by some function $s_p$, then take $s_p(\|x\|_p^p)$. Using $s_p$ avoids differentiability issues at $x=0$.

Comment: This question seems ill-posed.  One can define a function $x\mapsto\|x\|_\infty$ which will "approximate" the infinity norm of a vector in the very best way.  But presumably this function doesn't have certain properties that you want it to have.  So, what properties are those?

Comment: @anonymous The title says "smooth" (though the body of the question doesn't).